# How to plot many related data sets efficiently in parameter space in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, plot, parameters

If I have an array, array1 that I am plotting vs array2, and I want to keep changing a parameter in array1 and plotting all those, is there an efficient way to do this?

For example, if I want to divide array1 by different numbers and plot vs array2. So I want array1/2,array1/3,array1/4,array1/5......array1/100 and plot all of those vs array2 on the same plot. How would I go about doing this?

So for example. Array1=(1,2,3,4)  I want to do, Array1/2=(1/2,1,3/2,2), Array,1/3=(1/3,2/3,1,4/3), all the way to Array1/100=(1/100,2/100,3/100,4/100) and then plot all 100 of these arrays vs some Array2 on the same plot.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you were asking for...

```
    ## Arrays ##
    array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
    array2 = [4, 8, 12, 16, 20, 24, 28, 32, 36]

    #For item in array1
    for x in array1:
        print(" ")# Blank for readability
    #For each item in array 2
    for y in array2:
        #Do math
        z = x/y
        #Print math
        print(x, "/", y, "=", z)
        #Readability again
        print("----------------------------------")
```

The output for the above is:

```
1 / 4 = 0.25
----------------------------------
1 / 8 = 0.125
----------------------------------
1 / 12 = 0.08333333333333333
----------------------------------
1 / 16 = 0.0625
----------------------------------
1 / 20 = 0.05
----------------------------------
1 / 24 = 0.041666666666666664
----------------------------------
1 / 28 = 0.03571428571428571
----------------------------------
1 / 32 = 0.03125
----------------------------------
1 / 36 = 0.027777777777777776
----------------------------------

2 / 4 = 0.5
----------------------------------
2 / 8 = 0.25
----------------------------------
2 / 12 = 0.16666666666666666
----------------------------------
2 / 16 = 0.125
----------------------------------
2 / 20 = 0.1
----------------------------------
2 / 24 = 0.08333333333333333
----------------------------------
2 / 28 = 0.07142857142857142
----------------------------------
2 / 32 = 0.0625
----------------------------------
2 / 36 = 0.05555555555555555
----------------------------------
```

....etc.

Comment: No what I want is to plot array1 on y-axis vs array2 on x-axis. Then I want to plot array1 divided by 2 (array1/2) on y -axis vs array2 on x-axis. Then array1 divided by 3 (array1/3) on y-axis vs array2, then array1/4 and so on. I want to plot all these on the same plot. I edited the original post for clarity.